# Synchronized list in java Collections Framework

Tags: list, multithreading, collections, concurrency, synchronized

In the below Java code, I am trying to create a synchronized List from normal ArrayList and then performing the multithreading operation but still it gives ConcurrentModificationException. Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

```
package Concurrent_Collections;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * 
 * @author Nitesh Agrawal
 *
 */

public class DemoForConcurrentModificationException extends Thread {

    static List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static List<Integer> synchronizedList;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main Thread");
        synchronizedList = Collections.synchronizedList(myList);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            synchronizedList.add(i);
        }

        DemoForConcurrentModificationException t = new DemoForConcurrentModificationException();
        t.start();
        for (Integer k : synchronizedList) {
            System.out.println("Main");
            System.out.println(k);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Child Thread");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronizedList.add(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: See the JavaDoc for [Collections.synchronizedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-). An iteration must be manually synchronized and the for-each loop is syntax sugar that uses an iterator.

Comment: An iterator becomes invalid if the collection is modified during the iteration. This is unrelated the multi-threading and synchronization. It would be the same if you called `add(100)` on the list within the loop, in the same thread.